# Lucid Hydra (LucidLogix) Technology Support

Tags: 11.10, intel, 12.04

I will soon be buying an Intel Z68 motherboard (Sandy Bridge) which supports Lucid Hydra and Lucidlogix Virtu GPU Virtualization. Are this supported on Ubuntu 11.10 or 12.04. If not, what or how will Ubuntu run while using this type of hardware.

The last article I read about this was in Phoronix but it was almost a year ago: http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=OTIxOQ (Would be good if they made an updated one for 12.04)

I only use the PC right now for making small videos, visiting askubuntu 50 times a day and
maybe playing l4d2, web programming and using virtualbox.

Comment: i'm using an asrock board here with that lucid virtu mvp stuff, and the fact that the virtu stuff doesn't work on linux doesn't mean anything other than you don't get to use their feature that either puts work on the gpu, or if it's small work, it'll use the cpu's IGP. so no, not really relevant, and i've heard as well that even on windows it isn't all that great (maybe that will change though, who knows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No is the short answer for linux support of the Virtu GPU Virtualization by Lucid.

If you look on the Phoronix forums you will find many references to the lack of support with linux, notably [this apparent response](http://phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?22415-Lucid-Hydra-support-for-linux) from Lucid themselves. This is more than likely due to the lack of high end games available for linux in the first place - it also apparently has poor performance on a Windows environment and for the extra cost may not be worth the effort.

What will this mean for the motherboard to be supported under Ubuntu? I'm not sure but my guess would be the built in chip will be able to be disabled in bios so it is likely to allow the board to be used.

As this technology is for improved gaming performance and your primary use in Ubuntu is not really about gaming my recommendation would be to look into a different motherboard unless you will be dual booting with Windows and gaming with it.

Comment: How about if I want to play a game on Linux. Will I be able to disable it from the BIOS to run Ubuntu with no problems?

Comment: I really cannot say - I am only _assuming_ you can disable it in the bios I guess the only way to know for sure would be to buy it and try it. Ubuntu may well just ignore the chip anyway....

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to use something like [longene 0.4 beta Ubuntu package](http://www.longene.org/download.php), which allows running Windows kernel mode hardware drivers (limited to Windows binaries) on Linux.